# Is the set of binding constrains of linear programming unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming

Consider the following linear program
$\min c^Tx$ s.t. $Ax\leq b$,
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$
We know that the optimal solutions $x^*$ of the above linear program are not unique. And we also know that for an optimal solution $x^*$, some constraints are binding, defined as
$B=\{i\in[m]|A_ix=b_i\}$, where $A_i$ is the $i$th row of matrix A. My question is that is the set of binding constraints $B$ unique for a given linear program? how to prove that or disapprove that?

Answer (score 2):

Different basic feasible solutions will have different sets of binding constraints.  That is, a basic feasible solution is determined by the set of binding constraints for it.

Comment: Does there exists two optimal solutions with different sets of binding constraints?

Comment: If there is more than one optimal solution and at least one of them is **basic**, then yes.  That basic optimal solution is determined by its set of binding constraints, and for any other optimal solution at least one of those must be non-binding.  On the other hand, there are examples with no basic optimal solutions.  For example, consider $\min x_1 + x_2$ s.t. $x_1 + x_2 \le 0$.  The optimal solutions are $x_1 = -x_2$, $x_2$ arbitrary, and each of these have the one constraint $x_1 + x_2 \le 0$ binding.

Comment: Thanks! Does this still hold for quadratic program with linear constraints?